# Shared Preferences Appearing On-Screen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, saving-data

I am creating an attendance tracker for a summer camp, where counsellors can input the time their camper signed in by typing into an `editText` and pressing the save button. **This basic string should be saved into a textbox and loaded onto the screen every time the app is loaded**. There are multiple boxes like this so the counsellors can track what times each student came in / left every day.

I have used `sharedPreferences` to save the input from the counsellor when a button is pressed, and then display it using another button. However, **I CANNOT GET THE TEXT TO APPEAR ON THE SCREEN WHEN I CLOSE AND REOPEN THE APP**. Is my code missing something??

```
public class AttendancePage extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mondayMorn;
TextView displayMonMorn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_page);
    String counsellorName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Senior Counsellor Name");

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counsellorName);
    tv.setText(counsellorName + "'s");

    mondayMorn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText37);
    displayMonMorn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayMonMorn);
}

public void saveInput (View view) {
    SharedPreferences checkInMon = getSharedPreferences("LoginTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = checkInMon.edit();
    editor.putString("mondayIn", mondayMorn.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void updateSettings (View view){
    SharedPreferences checkInMon = getSharedPreferences("LoginTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String time = checkInMon.getString("mondayIn", "");

    displayMonMorn.setText(time);
}
```

Comment: try using commit() method for saving the shared preference file.

Comment: Where do you call `saveInput(...)`? Since you're obviously not using the data binding library and it cannot be found in your code, are you sure the click listener is properly set?

Comment: You're right, I did not properly set it. Again like I said my info does save to sharedPreferences but does not remain displayed after the app is closed.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy , how would I go about properly setting the click listener? My apologies I am a bit of a beginner...

Comment: @user8384402 Well, generally you should set like `findViewById(R.id.yourButtonsId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View view) {saveInput(view);}});`. But if you see the toast "Saved" now, it's not the problem. What the problem might be is that you never call `updateSettings(...)` in your `onCreate(...)`. Remove the `view` parameter and call it at the end of `onCreate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = checkInMon.edit();
editor.putString("mondayIn", mondayMorn.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

with:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = checkInMon.edit();
editor.putString("mondayIn", mondayMorn.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

that should at least save the data in preferences.

Comment: There's no real difference between `apply()` and `commit()` other than being async and sync respectively, which in this case doesn't matter anything since the process is _likely_ not getting killed before the data could be written to the permanent storage.